# Loop through pages and return product links in single array

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have the code I obtained with some help and it can be found at this link [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69881233/get-a-link-if-the-discount-is-greater-than-the-given-value). It works well in principle, but the problem is that it returns links and arrays for each page separately. However, I want it to return links in a single array for all pages together. I need to create a string `var all_links = []`  and push all the links from each page into it `all_links.push(...links)` and then return them like `return all_links` But the problem is that I’m failing because I don’t know exactly how to do it in this case. I am a pure beginner with no prior knowledge in coding

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const minDiscount = 20;

async function getLinks() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const url = 'https://www.mytoys.de/spielzeug-spiele/holz/';

    await page.goto(url);

    // getting all the products, this will return an array of ElementHandle
    while(await page.$(".pager__link--next")){
        await page.waitForSelector(".pager__link--next")
        await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
        await page.click('.pager__link--next')
        await page.waitForTimeout(1500);
        const products = await page.$$('.prod-grid.js-prod-grid .prod-grid__item.js-prod-grid_item');
        const proms = await Promise.allSettled(
            products.map(async (prod) => {
                // searching for a discount on each product
                const disc = await prod.$$eval(
                    '.prod-grid.js-prod-grid .prod-flag.prod-flag-sale',
                    (discount) =>
                        discount.map((discItem) =>
                            discItem.innerText.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/\D+/g,'0')
                        )
                );
                // if it has a discount
                if (disc.length > 0) {
                    // we parse the discount to Integer type to compare it to minDiscount
                    const discountInt = parseInt(disc[0], 10);
                    if (discountInt >= minDiscount) {
                        // we get the link of the product
                        const link = await prod.$$eval('.prod-grid.js-prod-grid .prod-tile__link.js-prodlink', (allAs) => allAs.map((a) => a.href));
                        if (link.length > 0) {
                            // push an object containing the discount and the link of the product
                            return link[0];
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            })
        );
        const bulkArray = proms.map((item) => {
            if (item.status === 'fulfilled') return item.value;
        });
        const endArray = bulkArray.filter(item => item !== null);
        console.log(endArray);
    }
}
    
getLinks();
```

Please help and be merciful as I am just starting to learn the basics

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleanup to get you started:

```
const products = await page.$$eval('.prod-tile', divs => divs.map(div => {
  return {
    url: div.querySelector('a')?.href
    discount: div.querySelector('.prod-flag-sale')?.innerText
  }
}))
```

At this point just follow the next links and do the same thing for each page.

Comment: Thanks for the help, which unfortunately doesn't help me much because I don't know where to place this code and how it helps with my problem. The code I have works fine. Successfully retrieves all product links that have a 20% or higher discount. I only have a problem that it returns links and arrays for each page separately, **but I want all the links in a single array for all pages together**

Comment: Just merge them with destructuring [...page1, ...page2]

Comment: Like I said, I’m a total beginner. I started learning two weeks ago and I have no experience with coding. I would really be very grateful if you could help me with the whole code. This will also make it easier for me to understand the whole concept